# Ошибка при сборке проекта

Tags: java, gradle, firebase

Создал новый проект для того, чтобы опробовать FirebaseUI Auth. Сделал все как сказано [здесь](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui).

Вот что получилось:

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
        }

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.b_ale.testauth"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    //Добавленные
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

То есть это просто пустой проект с подключенным FireBase и одной добавленной зависимостью. Однако при сборке появляется ошибка:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Нашел [вот эту](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#about) статью и пытался с ее помощью решить проблему. На сколько я понял - проблема в том, что в этой единственной добавленной мною зависимости слишком много методов. Как сказано в той статье - если minSdkVersion >= 21 то достаточно просто добавить строку **`multiDexEnabled true`** в раздел `defaultConfig` . Но это не помогло и ошибка осталась та же. Помогите пожалуйста ее решить.